Privacy comparison between AWS Bedrock vs running directly on EC2?
I would like to run some personally-sensitive data through an LLM, but I'm too nervous about my data leaking to use hosted services like Claude.ai or ChatGPT.com.
I'm trying to compare the privacy risks of these two alternatives:
1. Run LLaMA/whatever on an AWS EC2 instance
This is obviously not as private as running things locally, but I roughly understand how data is transmitted/processed/stored on EC2 and, given that, I'm comfortable with this option.
2. Using AWS Bedrock (or GCP Vertex AI)
This is way more convenient and allows running non-public models like Claude, but I don't understand the architecture enough to evaluate the privacy risks.
How is data transmitted/processed/stored on AWS Bedrock? What's a good way to reason about the risk of data leaking?
